# Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution) show error in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I am used ubuntu 16.04 and try to install atom editor using following commands:-

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/atom
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install atom
```

But can't istall show error :-

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_7.x xenial InRelease                                                                   
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                    
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                    
Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                                            
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                             
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease     
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 atom : Depends: git
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Please tell us how to solov this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apt-get can't install anything due to broken dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47461291/apt-get-cant-install-anything-due-to-broken-dependencies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to run the proposed solution ?

```
apt-get -f install
```

If this doesn't work, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) is a list of other possible solutions to this issue.