# Apt-get can't install anything due to broken dependencies

Tags: debian, apt, libc, dpkg

Whenever I run apt-get install for any package I get this error

```
➜  ~ sudo apt-get install clang-5.0

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 gcc-7-multilib : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed

 libc6-dev-x32 : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (= 2.25-2) but it is not going to be installed

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And when I run sudo apt --fix-broken install I get this error

```
Unpacking libc6-dev-i386 (2.25-2) ...

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.25-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/bits', which is also in package libc6-dev-amd64:i386 2.25-2

Errors were encountered while processing:

 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.25-2_amd64.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: first advice, try `aptitude` command, it will try to find solution automatically for you.

Comment: What is the output of  `cat /etc/apt/souces.list` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`?

Answer (score 6):

I fixed it by first running

sudo dpkg -r libc6-dev-i386

then by running
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386.

Comment: didn't work for me dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove libpng12-0:amd64 which isn't installed

Comment: Errors were encountered while p
rocessing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb

Answer (score 2):

I had tried the following

- sudo dpkg --configure -a
- sudo apt-get -f install
- sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
- sudo apt --fix-broken
- sudo apt-get -f install

but the problem still persisted, then this method worked for me.
**first:**
Move the /etc/apt/ folder to a temporary location [you my need Admin permission (sudo)]
then run

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt full-upgrade

delete the auto generated /etc/apt/ folder
then i return the previous /etc/apt/ folder back to its original location
and run

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt full-upgrade

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens as a result of 'Unmet dependencies for installed packages'

Open the terminal and run these commands in the following order:

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt --fix-broken install`
- `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
- `sudo apt-get clean`

Answer (score 0):

You have to do:

```
$ sudo apt purge libc6-dev-x32
```

and then add any other packages that `apt purge` is showing after the same command until there's no more package shown. This worked for me. Here's an example: https://askubuntu.com/a/1312145/165324

Answer (score 0):

Actually the command `apt --fix-broken install` needs a bit modification and it would work just fine.

The following worked for me:

```
sudo apt install --fix-broken
```

Answer (score 0):

Force Reconfigure or Remove Broken Packages with DPKG

1. Reconfigure DPKG, the base package management system, with the following command:

   **sudo dpkg --configure -a**
2. Check if DPKG marked some packages as needing a reinstall.

   **sudo dpkg -l | grep ^..R**
3. If the command above returns a list of one or more packages, try removing the packages by typing:

   **sudo dpkg --purge --force-all package-name**
4. After you finish troubleshooting, run the following command to clean up the system:

   **sudo apt clean**
5. Then update the repositories:

   **sudo apt update**
6. Then upgrade the repositories:

   **sudo apt upgrade**

Hope it helps.