# Update error on Debian 8

Tags: debian

I hope this is the right forum for this question. I am trying to do an update on Debian, but gets errors

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  exim4-base : Depends: exim4-config (>= 4.82) but it is not going to      
  be installed or exim4-config-2
  Recommends: mailx
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Doing as recommended also gives error:

```
# echo Y | apt-get -f install
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  exim4-config
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  postfix
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  exim4-config
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/503 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1130 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog debconf: 
(TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: 
dpkg: error processing package postfix (--remove):
  package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
  postfix
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It seems that a disrupted postfix installation is one of the problems. Y/n does not work either. Hence the echo Y |. But I cannot reinstall Postfix. Gives another error. Tried all suggestions on internet, but all get different errors.

This did not work [Apt-get can't install anything due to broken dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47461291/apt-get-cant-install-anything-due-to-broken-dependencies)

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: the real error seems to be this part "unable to initialize frontend: Dialog debconf: 
(TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)". What type of console are you using, is there something special about it?

Comment: Webmin. But I get same error using Mac Terminal. Still complaining about Postfix. Though the Y/n works.